# nested variables in Replace regex Ansible [ templating Error

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the following task :

```
pre_tasks:
- name: Disable nodes from the load balancer
  replace:
    path: "/USR/{{ ansible_user }}/{{ apache_directory }}/conf.d/balancers.conf"
    regexp: 'BalancerMember.*{{ balancer_members.[item].http.[inventory_hostname].url }}.*'
    replace: '#BalancerMember.*{{ balancer_members.[item].http.[inventory_hostname].url }}.*'
  with_items:
    - "portail_cluster"
    - "portail_cluster_se"
    - "portail_cluster_pentaho"
    - "ws_cluster"
    - "portail_longtimeout"
    - "portail_core"
  delegate_to: groups.front
  register: result
```

when i execute i get the following error:

```
TASK [Disable nodes from the load balancer] ********************************************************************************
task path: /USR/indus/work/etg-test/etg.file.deploy.app.yml:7
fatal: [sashimi2-pprod]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: #BalancerMember.*{{ balancer_members.[item].http.[inventory_hostname].url }}.*"
}
fatal: [wsashimi2-pprod]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: #BalancerMember.*{{ balancer_members.[item].http.[inventory_hostname].url }}.*"
}
```

Can some one understand what's going wrong with this syntax?
thanks in advance ^_^ !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was a syntax problem i changed text.[varibl].text with text[variable].text.
here is the the fix:

```
 - name: Disable web nodes from the load balancer
      replace:
        path: "/USR/{{ ansible_user }}/{{ apache_directory }}/conf.d/balancers.conf"
        regexp: "^ *BalancerMember.*{{ balancer_members[item].http[inventory_hostname].url }}.*"
        replace: "    #BalancerMember {{ balancer_members[item].http[inventory_hostname].url }}"
      delegate_to: server-ip
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe expansion of variables happens only for strings enclosed in `""`, not for strings in `''`.

It is briefly described in [Ansible documentation - YAML Gotchas](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas)

Comment: how do you think an can use a variable within the regex module

Comment: @MehdiMouslih AFAIK regexp expansion is happening __after__ passing to the module. Currently I am using `regexp: "^[#]?{{item.key}}"` and `regexp: "^(?!#)(.*)Match"` and it works.

Comment: I think the problem is in the variable [item] and [inventory_hostname] that are wraped in another variable